# Laravel 5.5: Blade forces https on external URLs

Tags: php, laravel, http, https, laravel-blade

i'm displaying external Website Links from my Users in a Profile Page. The URL Format is: `www.xyz.com`. When i put a `http://` before the `{{ url }}` Laravel changes the Protocoll automatically to `https://`. In the Result a lot of the Websites don't open properly. I set the `APP_URL` in the `.env File` to 
`https://domain` because i want to use SSL in the App.

Laravel (Blade) is removing the `http://` from the URL when i just want to print the Variable too. Even when i put `http://` right in front the URL in the DB (MySQL) i still have the same problem.

All i do in the Controller is:

`$user = \App\User::find($id);`

After 2 days of research i'm reaching out to the community. Basically i'm searching for something like `secure_url()` inverse.

What i tried:

`{{ url('http://'.$url) }}`

`{!! url('http://'.$url) !!}`

`{!! url(e('http://'.$url)) !!}`

`<a href="http://{{ $url }}">`

`{{ $url }}`

`Putting the Protocoll right in the DB`

What do i not get here? Thank you for any help.

**EDIT**

Laravel does this only when i visit my site over https.

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

It was the problem of the Laravel Cache Speed Package. I deactivated it and everything was back to normal. My fault, my bad.

Comment: `url()` is to link to internal urls. You can skip it

Comment: @kerbholz thank you for your answer. I tried it without already but without success.

Comment: Huh? Do as you said, put the complete URL in your database (including protocol etc.) and use `<a href="{{ $url }}">mYuRl</a>` to create a link in blade.

Comment: @kerbholz. unfortunatly i get the same result. Laravel changes http to https in the blade.

Comment: Strange, just set up a new Laravel project and everything works as expected. Any middleware/Javascript/.htaccess that could be causing this? If not I can't help, sorry

Comment: i checked it all. .htaccess is untouched and created by Laravel. No middleware/javascript causing this. Laravel does this on all links (internal/external) when i visit the site over https.